# how to open activity With Slider Animation left to right

Tags: android

i want to open Activity from Left To right Sliding ...On Button Click ..
i create anim xml

use this function for sliding animation with intent like

```
signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent s=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUpActivity.class);


    startActivity(s);
        ((Activity) getApplicationContext()).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidleft_to_right,R.anim.slideright_to_left);

                }
            });
```

But My App crashed and Give Error In Logcate

```
09-05 14:31:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15501): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
09-05 14:31:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at com.example.bounced.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
09-05 14:31:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-05 14:31:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16987)
09-05 14:31:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-05 14:31:39.761: E/AndroidRuntime(15501):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code to:

```
signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent s=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUpActivity.class);


            startActivity(s);
         overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidleft_to_right,R.anim.slideright_to_left);

                }
            });
```

**UPDATE:**

for backpress:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slideinfromleft, R.anim.slideouttoright);
}
```

Comment: animation Not Working ...When I call Finish();
then Its Working 
but When Pressed Back Button
then app exit

Comment: then ovverride onbackpressed()

Comment: Can U Update Ur Xml of anim......animation fil go activity and back to activity in slide anim

Comment: my animation files will be not similar with that of yours.You can change the respective animation files within  overridePendingTransition();

Comment: and One More TO you Please Solve lil Problem 

I want to show User_image and username .in Sliding Menu 

I created Sliding Menu But Can not add .what I want At top of Item of Slide Menu ..
If U tell To Ask Question ..Answer i Will Accept Ur Answer 
plzzz

Comment: and that is a different question.You can ask a separate question for that.

Comment: No One Answering My Question Using Actionbar Library ...
[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481114/how-to-set-logged-user-image-in-sliding-menu-item-using-actionbarsherlock)

please Answer This Question

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast the ApplicationContext (which is most of the time a class Application) to Activity.

Just remove that part and leave that :

```
startActivity(s);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidleft_to_right,R.anim.slideright_to_left);
```

Comment: animation Not Working ...When I call Finish();
then Its Working 
but When Pressed Back Button
then app exit

Answer (score 0):

you need res/anim.xml for support left to right Animation

```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shareInterpolator="false">

        <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
         android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
         android:duration="700"/>

   </set>
```

.class file

```
  this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enter, R.anim.animation_leave);
        (OR)
  this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slidleft_to_right,R.anim.slideright_to_left);
```